# I'm wondering where to find Moonstone Ore in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been looking throughout caves and such but I can't find any moonstone. Is there a special place that I can find it (Besides blacksmiths)?

Comment: Why, on the moon, of course! I kid, I kid. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The Skyrim wiki has compiled a nice list of all the places you can mine moonstore ores:

> - 7 veins in Mzulft (The Staff of Magnus quest required)
> - 5 veins in Soljund's Sinkhole, along with 3 loose ore in the mine and 2 ingots on a shelf within the crypt.
> - 2 veins in Blackreach.
> - 2 veins in Stony Creek Cave, southeast of Windhelm.
> - 2 veins northwest of Silent Moons Camp. Go up a steep hill. The veins are guarded by a bear or sometimes a sabre cat (depending on the
>     Dragonborn's level) at the slope of the  mountainside.
> - 1 vein on top of the mountain between Nightcaller Temple and Winterhold Imperial Camp.
> - 1 vein in Cronvangr Broodlair, in Cronvangr Cave.
> - 1 vein North of Skyborn Altar.
> - 1 vein in Crystaldrift Cave, southwest of Riften and west of Lost Tongue Overlook.
> - 1 vein near the gate to Cyrodiil, one to the right (follow the road south of Helgen. Takes some time).
> - 1 vein south of Wayward Pass, on one of the rock formations near the pathway.
> - 1 vein is East of Angi's Camp overlooking a cliff.
> - 1 vein south of Morthal, by a dragon burial mound.
> - 1 ore can be found on a shelf below deck in the Wreck of the Brinehammer.
> - 1 vein deep inside Tolvald's Crossing.
> - 1 vein at mountain peak on the south side of Raldbthar (easier to reach from Shearpoint and going east).
> - 1 vein along the crest between two mountain peaks east of Ironbind Overlook, an unmarked exit from Ironbind Barrow. The crest stretches
>     east from three unmarked Dwemer pillars near the first peak.
> - 2 veins inside of Darkfall Cave, just across the bridge. They can also be found as loot on Dwarven Spiders.
> - 1 vein inside of Wolfskull Cave, Wolfskull Ruins, in the second room on a small rock.
> - 1 vein at Last Vigil.

You can mine moonstone at any of these locations, just make sure you bring a pick (obviously). Some mining locations may have a spare pick laying around though.

Source: [Elder Scrolls Wiki: Moonstone Ore](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Moonstone_Ore)